# Ajuste Barra Superior Menu Hamburguer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, mvvm

Fiz um app com uma tela de Login a uma MainView que é um MasterDetail e um Detail. Está funcionando corretamente mas a tela superior está maior que o normal, conforme imagem; como eu configuro para que fique no tamanho correto?

[image: Imagem do APP onde tem a Barra azul esta maior que o normal.]

Segue código XAML do MainView, Master e Detail.

MainView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMApp"
             x:Class="MVVMApp.Views.MainView">
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Master.xaml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MVVMApp.Views.Master"
             BackgroundColor="Blue"
             Title="ListaViagem"
             Icon="Menu.png">

     <StackLayout Padding="20">
        <Label Text="Menu Lateral"></Label>
     </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage>
```

Detail.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MVVMApp.Views.Detail"
         Title="Detalhe">
</ContentPage>
```

Esse são os códigos dos xamls.

Códigos no MainView.CS de navegação:

```
        public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Master = new Master();
        this.Detail = new NavigationPage(new DetailPage());
        //this.BindingContext = new ViewModels.MainViewModel();
    }
```

Comment: Posta seu código xaml, por favor.

Comment: Postei o codigo dos XAMLs conforme solicitado.

Comment: Percebi que você está adicionando a masterpage e a detailpage através do C#. Quando vc adiciona a ContentPage que representa a DetailPage, tente colocar ela dentro de uma Navigation page. Exemplo: Detail = new NavigationPage(new DetailPage());

Comment: Mas isso quando vou realizar a navegação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema:
O erro estava na interface de navegação quando eu clicava no botão login ele executava a função de navegação para o MainView. Linha abaixo:

```
     public async Task NagateToMain()
    {
        MVVMApp.App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.MainView());

    }
```

O meu Main estava dentro de uma Page, como se tivesse duas paginas um dentro da outra. 
Para corrigir fiz a alteração para

```
    public async Task NagateToMain()
    {
        MVVMApp.App.Current.MainPage = new Views.MainView();
    }
```

Dessa forma realizei a correção. 
Obrigado pela ajuda.